# asp.net Allow unauthenticated only for some IP-Addresses

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I googled a lot but did not find an answer:

I have a webservice which requires windows-authentication.

**part of my web.config**

```
<!-- added for security reasons, in case of archiving from unix-clients remove it -->
<location path="Archive.asmx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

All windows-users can access this webservice normally.
BUT there is a service on a linux-server which should also use this webservice. So I want to allow the IP-Address of the Linux-server to call this webservice without authentication.

I don't want to remove the need to authenticate for all IPs (or users), only users from the linux-server should be able to access the webservice without authentication.

Comment: I'm not really sure if you can do using web config only. What you can do is implement some sort of custom authentication - allow anonymous authentication from any ip but in web service check ip and if it is not ip of your linux server then check if user is authenticated windows user. In other case don't check user identity.

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets is correct. For the sake of completness there are other ways - if I were you, I would create sevice account for linux server, and impersonate calls from linux under this service account. Other way around is to deploy service under different binding (port), remove authentication from web.config of that instance and allow access to that port on firewall only for ip of linux server